# Django request.POST does not contain the name of the button that submitted the form

Tags: django, forms, post, request, submit

I have a django form with two different submit buttons, on the view where the form is submitted to I need to know what submit button was pressed and take different actions accordingly.

From what I have read the submit button's name or id should be somewhere in the request.POST dictionary, but it not there!

This is a fragment of my form:

```
<form id="editPaperForm" action="{{paper.editURL}}" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" name="savePaperButton" id="savePaperButton" value="Save and Send Later"/>
   <input type="submit" name="sendPaperButton" id="sendPaperButton" value="Save and send"/>

   ...

</form>
```

In the view:

```
...
if 'sendPaperButton' in request.POST:
   return applicants_confirmSend(request, paperID)
else:
   return applicants_home(request)
```

sendPaperButton is never in the request.POST, and neither is the other one, should I be looking somewhere else?

The only idea I have is to add a hidden field and modify it via javascript before sending the form but that seems kind of redundant since I'm pretty sure that data should be there somewhere...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at what your browser sends via an http debugger such as Charles or Fiddler?

Comment: No, I have not, but you got me curious about what the browser was sending so I tried a different browser (was using Firefox 3.5, tried Chrome 4 and IE6), turns out Chrome and IE6 do send the button id and value, Firefox does not... guess hidden input with Javascript added value is my only option?

Comment: Why not use a checkbox or some other proper form element?

Comment: You could try using the button-element instead. But IE6 might have some issues with it if I recall correctly.

Comment: I tested with latest Firefox (3.5.7) and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't think a checkbox is appropriate for this situation. The two buttons do very different things, and checking a box is an extra step in what should be a simple button press. 

Anyway, I tried again this morning and now Firefox is sending it... this is very wierd... thankyou all for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: Is there a has_key function on request.POST -- this is a blind guess, but doesn't request.POST contain a list of key/value pairs and not a list if strings?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't forget to add the name and value parameters to your "button" or "input type=submit" fields of the form. I've had the same problem once and it drove me crazy.

In short, as request.POST contains a dict, you need a key and a value. The key corresponds to the name parameter of your button, and the dict's value to the button's value.

```
<button type="submit" value="preview">Preview</button>
```

won't be reflected in request.POST (there's no key for the POST dictionary!), whereas

```
<button type="submit" value="preview" name="preview">Preview</button>
```

will have a key "preview" with value "preview".

Comment: This is exactly what I forgot. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Having trouble in lastest version of Google Chrome with this, although it works fine with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: This fixed a similar problem I was having where form fields had unique IDs and no `name`, and the POST contained no data! Was driving me nuts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in Chrome, when I had two buttons using `<input/>` tags, it would actually treat  the button I didn't click as an input. That way, when I tested something like `'sendPaperButton' in request.POST`, it would return the opposite of what I wanted.

I changed these to `<button></button>` tags and it worked fine.